# No Reverse Match For Some URLs in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates, django-views

I am making an web app in Django 1.10 and am getting an annoying error which I cannot seem to resolve. In this project there are several Django app whose URLs function without problems and seem to have similar setup as the new Account app. However, this authentication app is giving me trouble.

What's more, the `account/register` URL works successfully and inserts a user into the database. I am not sure why some URLs work and other do not.

Here is the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /account/login/
Reverse for 'dashboard' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/account/login/
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'dashboard' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

Project's url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
    url(r'^orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    url(r'^shop/', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
    url(r'^cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                             document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Account app urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^edit/$', views.edit, name='edit'),

    # login / logout urls
    url(r'^login/$', django_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', django_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout-then-login/$', django_views.logout_then_login, name='logout_then_login'),

    # change password urls
    url(r'^password-change/$', django_views.password_change, name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password-change/done/$', django_views.password_change_done, name='password_change_done'),

    # restore password urls
    url(r'^password-reset/$', django_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password-reset/done/$', django_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[-\w]+)/(?P<token>[-\w]+)/$', django_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password-reset/complete/$', django_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Login template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Please, use the following form to log-in. If you don't have an account <a href="{% url "account:register" %}">register here</a></p>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="login-form">
        <form action="{% url "account:login" %}" method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
            <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
        </form>
        <p><a href="{% url "account:password_reset" %}">Forgotten your password?</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="social">

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Edit (views.py):**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import LoginForm, UserRegistrationForm, UserEditForm, ProfileEditForm
from .models import Profile


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            # Create the user profile
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return render(request,
                          'account/register_done.html',
                          {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})


@login_required
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,
                                 data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile,
                                       data=request.POST,
                                       files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your profile')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'account/edit.html', {'user_form': user_form,
                                                 'profile_form': profile_form})


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

Comment: On the POST.  GET works fine, i.e., the login template is displayed.

Comment: And what happens after you `POST`. What template are you rendering?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: I'll edit the question and post the entire `views.py` file.

Comment: By the way, `django_view.login` is defined by `from django.contrib.auth import views as django_views`. That is, I have been trying to use the standard authentication views.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere, in a template you haven't shown, you have done `{% url "dashboard" %}`, but that URL is under the account namespace. So you need to do `{% url "account:dashboard" %}`.

Comment: I just did a search for "dashboard" in the directory of the app and here is what I get: 
`./account/urls.py:8:    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
./account/views.py:72:def dashboard(request):
./account/views.py:73:    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})`